# Problem with jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery's tabs control and I add tabs dynamically with the following code:

```
 $("#div_Tabs").tabs("add", "/Game/PlayGame?matchID=" + matchID + "&isLooser=" + isLooser, userName);
```

After I add two tabs and when I select them one after the other, one of tabs dissapears by no reason.

I have no idea what causes the removal of tabs.

Comment: What is the content that is returned from that URL.. does it return embedded scripts as well?

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail than that. Could you provide an [example](http://jsfiddle.net) or live link that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @conqenator, that URL returns raw HTML and no scripts. After that I process the content of that HTML with javascript.

Comment: Can you post the content returned from both URL?